# How can I disable plugings for wordpress when doing posts with PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I load wordpress with my php code like this to do actions:

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); // Don't load theme support functionality
require( './wp-load.php' );
```

How could I also disable plugins temporarily when I want to add posts, etc? This would be to use less server resources...

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's actually a *good* way to do this. The best way is probably to run your function before plugins are loaded. Otherwise you're looking at programatically renaming the `/plugins` folder or `WP_PLUGIN_[DIR/URL]` constants which just screams "error prone"

Effectively you can hook into the first action hook available, which is [`muplugins_loaded`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/muplugins_loaded): [Source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). Especially if you have no `mu-plugins` to be run, it should be run almost instantaneously:

```
add_action( 'muplugins_loaded', 'run_before_plugins_load' );
function run_before_plugins_load(){
    if( condition == met ){
        // Insert your post here
        if( $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post ) ){
           exit(); // Post inserted, stop processing anything.
        } else {
           wp_die( 'Post not inserted' );
        }
    }
}
```

From there you'll have inserted a post and stopped any further propagation. Of course, you can replace `exit` and `wp_die` with whatever you want - it's just the fastest way I can see to run a WP function without actually loading plugins.